# How to combine values so when report is ran, the values associated with them sum as one final value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a report which has a odd situation:

I have a table as follows:

**Reasons**

| ReasonID | ReasonName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Burn |
| 2 | Weld Burn |
| 3 | Spot Burn |

**Container**

| Container | ReasonName | Defectqty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Burn | 4 |
| A | Weld Burn | 10 |
| B | Spot Burn | 15 |

What I want to do is combine all 3 values as 1 so that when I run a query like

```
Select container, defectqty 
from container 
where reasonname = 'burn' and container = 'A'
```

My output would look like this:

| Container | Defectqty |
| --- | --- |
| A | 14 |

I was assuming I would use a case condition but I am kind of lost

Comment: use a `GROUP BY`. You don't need `CASE`

Comment: Your sample data & query does not matches with the expected result You have `reasonname = 'burn'` in your query, based on your sample data, the `Defectqty` should be just `4` not `14`

Comment: If you cannot accurately define your goal, you will struggle to implement it. You said "combine all 3 values as 1" but your desired output combines only 2 rows (both for Container A). Does the value of ReasonName even matter? Are you simply summing to get a single total for Container? You have lots of questions and have not yet marked a single answer. How about doing your part to make this website work for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
select container,case
when container='A' Then sum(Defectqty)
when container='B' Then sum(Defectqty)
end as Defectqty
from container group by container
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `CASE` expression in the query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below sql query, using derived table. You don't need join. All you want is available in single table: Container.

```sql
declare @table table(container char(1), reasonName varchar(30), defectqty int)

insert into @table values
('A','Burn',    4),
('A','Weld Burn',   10),
('B','Spot Burn',   15)

SELECT container, reasonName, total_defectqty from
(select *, sum(defectqty) over (partition by container) as total_defectqty from @table) as t
WHERE ReasonName = 'Burn' and container = 'A'
```

| container | reasonName | total_defectqty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Burn | 14 |

Comment: You know better - that generates a syntax error as the cte does not expose the reasonname column. And that is no improvement over OP's query since OP wants to combine rows containing either Burn and Weld Burn together.

Comment: @SMor, sorry. I have corrected the query and tested the same.